# BatchUpdate on Sheets with userEnteredValue as an object

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Looking to provide a request object to BatchUpdate so both cell values and formatting can be updated. I am constructing the following request object:

```
   const request = [{
    updateCells: {
      range: {
        sheetId:grid.sheetId,
        startRowIndex: grid.startRow,
        endRowIndex: grid.endRow,
        startColumnIndex: grid.startCol,
        endColumnIndex:grid.endCol
      },
      rows: [
        {
          values: [
          {
            userEnteredFormat: {
              backgroundColor: {
                red: 1,
                green: 0.4,
                blue: 0.4
              }
            },
            userEnteredValue: {
              stringValue: {object containing the row}
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    fields: "userEnteredFormat,userEnteredValue"
   }
   }];
```

Apparently I get an error "Starting an object on a scalar field".
Is there some different request type to be made to provide the row as an array or object?
Looking at the docs [https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/sheets#RowData], it doesn't look like it.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although unfortunately, I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand `{object containing the row}` of `stringValue: {object containing the row}`, in your request body, if `{object containing the row}` of `stringValue: {object containing the row}` is an object like `{key: "value"}, an error like` starting an object on a scalar field`occurs. I thought that this might be the reason for your current issue. And also, when an array like`["sample value"]`is used, an error like`Proto field is not repeating, cannot start list`occurs. In this case, please use a string value like`stringValue: "sample value"`. Please be careful about this.

From your question of `Is there some different request type to be made to provide the row as an array or object?`, if you want to use an array including values to this request body, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  const spreadsheetId = "###"; // Please set your Spreadsheet ID.
  const grid = { sheetId: 0, startRow: 0, startCol: 0 }; // Please set your gridrange.
  const values = [["sample value1", "sample value2"], ["sample value3", "sample value4"]]; // Please set your values as 2 dimensional array.

  const request = [{
    updateCells: {
      range: {
        sheetId: grid.sheetId,
        startRowIndex: grid.startRow,
        startColumnIndex: grid.startCol,
      },
      rows: values.map(r => ({
        values: r.map(c => ({
          userEnteredFormat: { backgroundColor: { red: 1, green: 0.4, blue: 0.4 } },
          userEnteredValue: { stringValue: c }
        }))
      })),
      fields: "userEnteredFormat,userEnteredValue"
    }
  }];
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({ requests: request }, spreadsheetId);
}
```

- When this script is run, `values` are put from the cell "A1" in `sheetId`.
- About `grid`, in this case, I think that when the start cell coordinate (the top left side) is put, this script can be used.

#### Note:

- This is a simple sample script for using an array. So, if your `values` include numbers, boolean, and formulas, please use the keys of `numberValue`, `boolValue` and `formulaValue`. Please be careful about this. And, if you are using a JSON object, when you convert it to a 2-dimensional array, you can use it using this script.

#### Reference:

- [UpdateCellsRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#updatecellsrequest)

Comment: Many Thanks Tanaike, that's what I ended up doing myself! I had an error in my code using the correct array/object sequence, but now it's working great!

Comment: Your solutions are always very elegant, I am using many of the functions you have given in the past in my code!.

Comment: if you may help please with a question that popped up while looking at your code: how can you pass a parameter into the nested map? As an example, if you want the cell formatting to be a variable, how can you pass this argument into the nested map? Can't seem to find that anyplace...

Comment: @user2852591 Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new question of `how can you pass a parameter into the nested map? As an example, if you want the cell formatting to be a variable, how can you pass this argument into the nested map? Can't seem to find that anyplace...`, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your new question. But, I would like to support you. So, can I ask you about the detail of your new question?

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me. I am referring to the userEnteredFormat: { backgroundColor: { red: 1, green: 0.4, blue: 0.4 } }  statement within the nested map anonymous function. I want  to make this to be a variable, so need to pass it as an argument.

Comment: @user2852591 Thank you for replying. From your reply, you are using only the value of `{ backgroundColor: { red: 1, green: 0.4, blue: 0.4 } }` as a variable, and you want to use this to all cells. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: I want to be able to pass the r,g,b values as arguments from the outer code block, myFunction

Comment: @user2852591 Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `I want to be able to pass the r,g,b values as arguments from the outer code block `. Can I ask you the detail of your new question?

Comment: Sure, so the code to be like this `rows: values.map(r => ({
        values: r.map(c => ({
          userEnteredFormat: { backgroundColor: { red: var1, green: var2, blue: var3 } },`

Comment: @user2852591 Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your 2nd question. I'm worried that I might trouble you because I cannot resolve your various questions soon, while I could resolve your 1st question. So, in this case, I would like to recommend posting it as a new question. By this, it will help a lot of users think of a solution. If you can cooperate to resolve your 2nd question, I'd be glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: Sure, I have posted a new question here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75281225/passing-arguments-in-a-nested-map-anonymous-function]