# Passing arguments in a nested map anonymous function

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am looking to how you can pass arguments into a nested anonymous map function.
So in a function like the below, the values of red, green, blue in the nested map are hardcoded.
How can parameters be passed into the nested map?

```
function myFunction() {
  const spreadsheetId = "###"; // Please set your Spreadsheet ID.
  const grid = { sheetId: 0, startRow: 0, startCol: 0 }; // Please set your gridrange.
  const values = [["sample value1", "sample value2"], ["sample value3", "sample value4"]]; // Please set your values as 2 dimensional array.

  const request = [{
    updateCells: {
      range: {
        sheetId: grid.sheetId,
        startRowIndex: grid.startRow,
        startColumnIndex: grid.startCol,
      },
      rows: values.map(r => ({
        values: r.map(c => ({
         ** userEnteredFormat: { backgroundColor: { red: 1, green: 0.4, blue: 0.4 } }**,
          userEnteredValue: { stringValue: c }
        }))
      })),
      fields: "userEnteredFormat,userEnteredValue"
    }
  }];
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({ requests: request }, spreadsheetId);
}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: In your situation, how do you want to do the background color of each cell? For example, you want to use only one parameter like `{ red: 1, green: 0.4, blue: 0.4 }` to all cells of the added values?

Comment: No, the opposite, I want red, green blue to be variables

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `No, the opposite, I want red, green blue to be variables`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: Sure, how I can make each cell have a different background color?

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `how I can make each cell have a different background color?`, I think that I understood your question. I would like to prepare a modified script. Please wait for it.

Comment: I posted a modified script. Please confirm it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your situation, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function myFunctionb() {
  const spreadsheetId = "###"; // Please set your Spreadsheet ID.
  const grid = { sheetId: 0, startRow: 0, startCol: 0 }; // Please set your gridrange.
  const values = [["sample value1", "sample value2"], ["sample value3", "sample value4"]]; // Please set your values as 2 dimensional array.
  const backgroundColors = [[[1, 0.4, 0.4], [0.4, 1, 0.4]], [[0.4, 0.4, 1], [0.4, 0.4, 0.4]]]; // Please set your background colors as 2 dimensional array.

  const request = [{
    updateCells: {
      range: {
        sheetId: grid.sheetId,
        startRowIndex: grid.startRow,
        startColumnIndex: grid.startCol,
      },
      rows: values.map((r, i) => ({
        values: r.map((c, j) => ({
          userEnteredFormat: { backgroundColor: { red: backgroundColors[i][j][0], green: backgroundColors[i][j][1], blue: backgroundColors[i][j][2] } },
          userEnteredValue: { stringValue: c }
        }))
      })),
      fields: "userEnteredFormat,userEnteredValue"
    }
  }];
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({ requests: request }, spreadsheetId);
}
```

- When this script is run, 4 values are put from cell "A1" and also 4 different background colors are set from cell "A1".

Comment: Many Thanks for the modification. Please allow me to test it in my setting

Comment: @user2852591 Thank you for replying. About `Please allow me to test it in my setting`, yes. Of course.